# How to write a join var datacontext?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, join, var

```
DataContext db = new DataContext(conString);
var dvd = db.GetTable<DvdList>();
var category = db.GetTable<CategoryList>();
var query= from b in dvd 
           join category on dvd.CategoryId equals category.CategoryId  
           where b.Title.Contains(txtSearch.Text)
           select b;
GridView1.DataSource =query;
```

here has error "join category on dvd"

Comment: Why are you joining anyway? You don't seem to use the category.

Comment: Is is a C# compile error message or a runtime exception?

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to use `category` as both the range variable name *and* the collection name. Try this:

```
var query= from b in dvd 
           join c in category on dvd.CategoryId equals c.CategoryId  
           where b.Title.Contains(txtSearch.Text)
           select b;
```

(As noted in comments, the join is really just going to filter out DVDs whose category ID isn't in the category table... in your *real* query, are you actually using the category?)